# Как вставить картинку в код бота на Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Всем привет, появилась нужда вставить в код python-бота телеграмм картинку. Использую TelegramBotAPI. Вот пример кода-обработчика, картинку мне туда надо вставить:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_worker(call):
    if call.data == "1":
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        key_urlka = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Яндекс', url='https://yandex.ru', callback_data='urlka')
        keyboard.add(key_urlka)
        text1=(first)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text=text1, reply_markup=keyboard)

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)

ps - text1=(first) "first" где то выше в коде, там обычный текст
```

Answer (score 2):

```
photo = open('Путь к фото', 'rb')
bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text=text1, photo=photo,reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Если ответ помог, можешь пожалуйста поставить галочку слева рядом с моим ответом. @Ya_ne_sharru

Comment: А есть такой вопрос. Я прописываю C:\User\Users\ и так далее, но он выдает ошибку. C:\Users\Pc\Desktop\python - тут у меня фотка. После мне надо прописать после \python название картинки? Или я что то не понимаю

Comment: Закинь фото в папку со скриптом и поменяй на photo = open('НАЗВАНИЕФОТО.PNG', 'rb') . Просто по правилам, не нужно радоваться в комментариях, надо на деле, или галочка или стрелочка слева